# AngularJS: Applying Currency Filter to return value of custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am writing a custom filter to replace the value of zero with ' - ' for display purposes. However, if it is not zero, it should return input but filtered as currency. When I tried that, I get an unexpected token error.

```
angular.module('app')
        .filter('displaynullcurrency', function(){
            return function(input){
                if(!input){ return ' - '; }
                if(parseFloat(input) != 0){
                    return {{input | currency}};
                }
                return ' - ';
            };
        });
```

Comment: Why are you using the double bracket `{{ }}` notation in there? You can't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to use a `$filter` inside a javascript function you have to use it like this: `$filter('currency')(input)`, the syntax that you were using in your function is reserved for templates, try this instead:

```
angular.module('app')
        .filter('displaynullcurrency', function($filter){
            return function(input){
                if(!input){ return ' - '; }
                if(parseFloat(input) != 0){
                    return $filter('currency')(input);
                }
                return ' - ';
            };
        });
```

Comment: I know there was a downvote because I voted for the answer but the total is 0. However, I was wondering how YOU knew there was a downvote. Is there someplace on SO or somewhere on this page that tells you there are downvotes? I am just interested to know. AND despite the downvote, I appreciated your response ... thanks!

Comment: @jgravois Iknew it through 2 different ways: 1) First I got a notification saying that I had gotten an up-vote, and later when I came to see if there was some feedback from you I saw that my answer had a score of 0. 2) Once you reach a rep of 1000 you get this right: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user which allows you to see the break-down of up-votes/down-votes for any question or answer ;)

Comment: thanks for the explanation ... LOL since I never get any upvotes, I wouldn't know about the notification. Also, I wonder if the downvote was because you didn't inject $filter into the function? I did it without realizing you hadn't so the solution worked for me but maybe that was the reason

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to pipe a value in a directive inside a binding statement. You can only do that in your templates.

To return the input value filtered by currency, you should do something like this :

```
angular.module('app')
  .filter('displaynullcurrency', function($filter) {
    return function (input) {
      if (!input) { return ' - '; }
      if (parseFloat(input) != 0) {
        return $filter('currency')(input);
      }
      return ' - ';
    };
  });
```

Comment: Yeah but we don't really know what the OP want to do with it, so I let this as it was, bigger problem was the token error I think :)